# How to refresh a file reading every 5 minutes in Android?

Tags: android, file, android-activity, refresh, inputstream

Im trying to read a file every 5 minutes, but really I dont know how!

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button bVe, bCl, bCo, bAd;
File tarjeta = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bVe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bVehiculos);
    bCl = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bClientes);
    bAd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdmin);

    bVe.setOnClickListener(this);
    bCl.setOnClickListener(this);
    bAd.setOnClickListener(this);


    File file1 = new File(tarjeta.getAbsolutePath()+"/.Info/Prices", "values.txt");        
    try {
        FileInputStream fIn1 = new FileInputStream(file1);   
        InputStreamReader archivo1 = new InputStreamReader(fIn1);
        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(archivo1);
        String linea1 = br1.readLine();
        String texto1 = "";
        while (linea1!=null)
        {
            texto1 = texto1 + linea1 + "\n";
            linea1 = br1.readLine();
        }
        br1.close();
        archivo1.close();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Cant read", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

What I need is while I am in this activity, it reads the file every 5 minutes.

I will really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to check it every five minutes? You could use a `FileObserver`:

```
FileObserver observer = 
new FileObserver(Environment.getExternalStorageState() +"/documents/") {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(int event, String file) {
        if(event == FileObserver.MODIFY && file.equals("fileName")){ 
            Log.d("TAG", "File changed");
            // do something
        }
    }
};
```

Isn't that easier and less CPU/battery consuming, is it? See another nice example at https://gist.github.com/shirou/659180.

p.s. in your case you would probably use ...

```
new FileObserver(tarjeta.getAbsolutePath()+"/.Info/Prices/")

file.equals("values.txt")
```

... and possibly some more event types.

Just an idea ... Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
getHandler().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    void run() {
        (code to read file)
        getHandler().postDelayed(this,300000);
    }
});
```

What it does is push this Runnable into the ui thread, which posts itself into the same thread in 5 minutes (300000 ms).